# VS Code Sass formatter breaking up comma-separated variable values

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm somewhat new to VSCode and I'm having an issue with the scss beautifier, specifically with it putting comma separated values in variables onto new lines.

For example, the following code:

```
    $brandfont: "Domine", sans-serif;
    $brandred: rgb(189,6,40);
```

becomes:

```
    $brandfont: "Domine",
    sans-serif;
    $brandred: rgb(189,
    6,
    40);
```

Any ideas how to get this to stop without disabling the formatter completely?